# Induced topology in nested subsets

Tags: general-topology

Consider the sets $D \subset C \subset B \subset A$.

If does not make much sense to say "$D$ is open" unless we specify in which subset $D$ is open relative to which other subset.

For example, if $D$ is open in $C$ relative to $A$, we mean that $D = C \cap O_{A}$ where $O_{A}$ is an open set in $A$.

Are the 4 statements here equivalent?

1) $D$ is open in $C$ relative to $B$

2) $D$ is open in $C$ relative to $A$

3) $D$ is open in $B$ relative to $A$

4) $D$ is open in $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They are not equivalent.

If $A\subset B\subset C$, then $A$ open in $C$ $\implies$ $A$ open in $B$ relative to $C$. But converse is not true (it will be true if $B$ is also open in $A$). For example, consider$A=B=[0,1], C=(-1,2)$.

So $4\implies 1,2,3$ but 1,2,3 can't imply 4. Similarly, $3\implies1,2$, but neither 1 nor 2 implies 3.

But 1,2 are equivalent, i.e. $1\iff 2$.

$2\implies 1$
$D$ is open in $C$ relative to $A$, means $D = C \cap O_{A}$ where $O_{A}$ is an open set in $A$. Then $D = C \cap O_{B}$,where $O_{B}=B\cap O_{A}$ is an open set in $B$ with subspace topology.

$1\implies 2$
$D$ is open in $C$ relative to $B$, means $D = C \cap O_{B}$ where $O_{B}$ is an open set in $B$ with subspace topology. Hence $O_B = B \cap O_{A}$ where $O_{A}$ is an open set in $A$, Then $D = C \cap O_{B}=C\cap B \cap O_{A}=C \cap O_{A}$,where $O_{A}$ is an open set in $A$

So in general, $A\subset B\subset C\subset D$, you can fix the nearest layer and change the further layers, but when you want to change the nearest layer, you need to be careful.

Comment: Let us generalized this and let $D \subset A_{1} \subset A_{2} \subset A_{3} ... \subset A_{n}$, if $D$ is open in $A_{1}$ relative to $A_{2}$, does it mean that $D$ is open in $A_{1}$ relative to $A_{i}$, where $1 < i < n+1$?

Comment: @LateLearner Yes.